# Superslides -> Go to specific slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use Superslides to create an intro. I need that at first the background is white (image 0.jpg) and then when the mouse enters a div change to another image random.

My code is:

HTML

```
<div id="entra_mouse">
    <img src="imagenes/intro/logo.png" alt="" />
    <br /><br /><br />
    <a href="?s=home">Entrar / Enter</a>
</div>
<div id="slides">
  <div class="slides-container">
    <img src="imagenes/intro/0.jpg" alt=""  />
    <img src="imagenes/intro/1.jpg" alt="" id="img_aleatoria"  />
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('#slides').superslides({
        hashchange: false
      });

      $('#entra_mouse').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $('#slides').css('display','inline');

        var imagen_aleatoria = Math.round(Math.random()*6);
        $("#img_aleatoria").attr("src", "imagenes/intro/'+imagen_aleatoria+'.jpg");

        $('#slides').superslides('start');
      });
      $('#entra_mouse').on('mouseleave', function() {
        $('#slides').superslides('stop');
        $('#slides').css('display','none');
      });
    });
  </script>
```

The problem is when the mouse enters ($('#entra_mouse').on('mouseenter', function() {) always show image 1.jpg and not the random.

How I can fix it? =(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hej!

You can write $('#slides').data('superslides').animate(*something*).

In my case I have a gallery and when you click on a specific image on get the slide show on a overlay that slides from the top. I get the current index of the thumbnail clicked and animated the slideshow to match with the thumbnail:

```
$( thumbnail ).click(function() {
    var current = $(thumbnail).parent().children('a').index(this);
    $('#slides').data('superslides').animate(current);
});
```

Although I have to say that is not ideal, since I would like to go to a specific slide without animating the action. I haven't find a way to do so.

I hope that helps you! Good Luck!